# How can we create JSON schema to build a angular formly based forms on basis of plain JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-formly

We have a requirement in which we are planning to build a form according to the JSON received and convert it to JSON schema which is supported by formlyJsonschema, is there any way of achieving this?

```
Eg JSON:

{
 "isSignInRequired": true,
 "isEmployee": false,
 "noOfEmployees": {
 "minValue": 3,
 "maxValue": 50
 }
}
```

**Requirement:** If the value is a boolean convert to a type of toggle and if there is an integer or string value convert to a type of textbox

**Desired converted JSON Schema supported by *formlyJsonschema* is as follows:**

```
"schema" :[
{
 "properties": {
 "isSignInRequired": {
 "type": "toggle",
 "default": true
 },
 "isEmployee": {
 "type": "toggle",
 "default": true
 }
}
},
{
"description": "noOfEmployees",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"minValue": {
"type": "integer",
"title": "minValue"
},
"maxValue": {
"type": "integer",
"title": "maxValue",
"minLength": 3
}
}
}]
```

I tried using some JSON schema-based examples but was not able to fit my requirement into it, example is as follows:

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-editor-usingformly?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Will you also want array support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `default` and `maxLength` assertions are impossible to derive from one sample of data, but you can assume `type` and `properties`. There may be other assertions that you may choose to assume, such as `additionalProperties`.

```
var data = {
    "isSignInRequired": true,
    "isEmployee": false,
    "noOfEmployees": {
        "minValue": 3,
        "maxValue": 50
    }
};

// could use lodash mapValues instead
var mapValues = (fn, data) => Object.keys(data).reduce((accum, key) => ({ ...accum, [key]: fn(data[key], key) }), {});

var toSchemaType = data =>
    Array.isArray(data)
        ? 'array'
        : typeof data;

var deriveSchema = (data, key) => ({
    type: toSchemaType(data),
    ...(key && { title: key }),
    ...(toSchemaType(data) === 'object' && {
        properties: mapValues(deriveSchema, data)
    })
});

deriveSchema(data)
```

Comment: You can modify the `toSchemaType` function to return `toggle`. I haven't done that because it's nonsense that your form technology would butcher json schema like that.

Comment: what would be the key parameter for function  deriveSchema() ?

Comment: We reduce over the keys in the data object, so key is `isSignInRequired`, `isEmployee`, etc. The key is passed in so that it can be used as the `title` of the schema. At the root object schema there is no key, so key param is optional.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I am able to build the form but I need small support in this, I am using arrays in the JSON, instead of schema type to array i am converting to type object , now i have properties with "name" in the json i wanna display labels for this here is the demo example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-editor-usingformly-nsyysx?file=src/app/app.component.ts  it would be helpful if you can look into this. Thank you!